# Linq coding style: inline if

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I've got a question about common practice of writing linq queries. Actually I had an argument with my colleague.

We have a boolean variable in case it's true - additional check is needed. in case it's false there should be no such a check.

There are 2 way to implement it in linq:

```
bool onlyForReturningCustomers;    
.....    
return context.Products.Where(product => product.StartTime >= fromDate 
                                && product.StartTime < toDate 
                                && (onlyForReturningCustomers ? product.IsReturningClient : true));
```

and the second:

```
bool onlyForReturningCustomers;
.....            
var q = context.Products.Where(product => product.StartTime >= fromDate && product.StartTime < toDate);

if (onlyForReturningCustomers) {
  q = q.Where(product => product.IsReturningClient);
}
return q;
```

The first one renders `case` statement in sql and when `onlyForReturningCustomers=false` the statement like `1=1` appears but this code is read a lot easier.

The second one is not so easy to read but it renders clear statement in sql without any junk.

Which one would you use?

Comment: It seems like you already have the tools/knowledge available to answer this.

Answer (score 4):

I might go for

```
bool onlyForReturningCustomers;
.....            
// Make a positively-named variable
bool includeAllCustomers = !onlyForReturningCustomers;
var q = context.Products.Where(product => product.StartTime >= fromDate 
                                       && product.StartTime < toDate
                                       && (includeAllCustomers 
                                           || product.IsReturningClient));

return q;
```

which is basically the same as your first way, but without the oddity of a conditional expression where one branch just says `true`.

Comment: Why didn't you just do (!onlyForReturningCustomers || product.IsReturningClient)? Saves using a variable :)

Comment: @mattytommo as a stylistic thing, I prefer boolean conditions to be expressed / consumed **positively**, which I believe aids understanding. I think there's some stuff on this in Code Complete (sorry, don't have it to hand right now)

Comment: ah fair enough, I'll agree with that :). +1 for your answer

Answer (score 4):

The second statement is easier to read, and also easier to maintain if you would have added business rules in the future for returning customers or other types of customers.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the first one because it looks like the second option is actually two round trips to the data.

I would also copy the SQL emitted by the LINQ statement, paste it into your favorite SQL tool *(e.g. SQL Server Management Studio)*, add `SET STATISTICS IO ON` above the `SELECT` statement and examine the logical reads necessary to execute the query (lower is better).

Comment: It shouldn't require two round-trips: LINQ queries are usually deferred until you actually ask for the results.